# "Go set a watchman" ("Пойди, поставь сторожа") by Harper Lee

Tags: перевод

14-го июля спустя более чем пятьдесят лет был опубликован [второй роман](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062409859) Харпер Ли, являющийся продолжением книги "Убить пересмешника".

Повсеместно название переводят как "Пойди, поставь сторожа", что, на мой взгляд, слишком буквально. 
Есть ли какое-нибудь выражение или название, которое бы более красиво передавало заглавие книги?

Comment: Could you please provide some context which would demonstrate what's wrong with the original translation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it but I think that americans are more familiar with the Bible texts and the meaning of the title is obvious for them.

Comment: I don't consider myself unfamiliar with the Bible but I failed to recognize this Bible quote on sight. Brief googling shows that a great deal of native English speakers did too.

Comment: Не самое известное место из Библии. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вам могу подать идею, как можно сгенерировать другие варианты перевода.
Идете сюда - https://www.biblegateway.com/
Набираете там Isaiah 21:6-12. Вы получите все основные варианты перевода Библии на английский язык. Один из которых Go set a watchman. Но там есть и другие варианты - post a lookout, set a looker и прочие. После чего вы можете создать собственные другие переводы этой фразы с имеющихся переводов на английский.

Еще один вариант http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=watchman Смотрите тут варианты перевода слова watchman и делаете другой перевод.

Недостаток всех этих методов - при переводе, который будет отличаться от синодального, потеряется аллюзия на известный стих Библии. А церковнославянский перевод архаичен.

Answer (score 15):

Это фраза из Библии, Исаия 21:6.

[Синодальный перевод](http://allbible.info/bible/sinodal/isa/21/):

```
Ибо так сказал мне Господь: пойди, поставь сторожа; пусть он сказывает, что увидит.
```

В [церковнославянском](http://www.bible-center.ru/ru/bibletext/slavonic_ru/isa/21:6) варианте — *«шед постави себе стража»*.

Comment: Верно. Но имелось в виду то, что название должно вызывать ассоциации у читателей. Возможно, что в Америке это более понятное название чем у нас, по крайней мере среди моих знакомых никто сразу не сказал, что "Пойди, поставь сторожа" - это цитата из Ветхого Завета.

Comment: Думаю, что и в США немного людей узнают эту фразу. Но, конечно, больше чем в России/Украине. Потому как изучение текстов Библии в США гораздо активнее и мощнее поставлено.

Comment: @optim1st В принципе можно было бы использовать приведенный выше церковнославянский перевод (аналогично тому, как было в свое время переведено название романа Сенкевича). Но "третьих" вариантов тут нет и быть не может.

Comment: @user4419802 Почему же не может? Существует еще, например,  современный русский перевод, который осуществлялся с 1980 по 2010 год. http://www.biblia.ru/books/modern_bible/main.html Или вы считаете, что после 1820-х или 30-х годов переводить Библию на русский уже нельзя? :)

Comment: SergZ  Господа, я, как и @user4419802, считаю, что раз автор назвал свое произведение цитатой из Библии, то, строго говоря, и переведена она должна быть соответствующей цитатой из общепринятого варианта языка перевода. Тем менее, мне, как читателю, то же "Будь настороже" приглянулось бы больше (по крайней мере было бы более понятно) нежели "Пойди, поставь сторожа". Но спорить тут не о чем, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Nikolay Ershov, абсолютно согласен. Именно так и талько так можно перевести. остальное - вообще не по теме.

Comment: @optim1st Мне вот кажется, вы вообще не с той стороны подходите. Есть такое довольно универсальное культурное явление, как названия-цитаты. Это могут быть даже цитаты из самого произведения, вроде *Look at the Harlequins!*. По большей части название-цитата интуитивно воспринимается как таковое, и для интерпретации содержащегося в нем намека на темы и сюжеты произведения знать источник цитаты вовсе необязательно. Я бы даже сказал, что Библия в таких случаях скорее фигурирует как обширный источник цитат, легко отделимых от содержательного и культурного контекста, чем как "собственно" Библия.

Comment: Guys, we have a nice http://chat.stackexchange.com/ for religious disputes. Please make like a *ъ* in a strong position and go on there.